# Not able to echo or alert message while using json in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello i want to echo an error message or alert it but it seems not working for me and giving an bydefault error dialog box.
Here is my code:

```
               if($param['aktion'] == 'remove-widget')
               {

                $count=mysql_query("Select dsnr_dashboard_widget from dashboard_widget_users where dsnr_yw_user=10");
                $count_result=mysql_num_rows($count);
                if($count_result<=1){  
                    echo '<script>alert("Cant delete all widgets")</script>';
                }

                $return = array(
                        'status' => 1,
                        'html'  => ''
                        );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
```

Comment: if it gives a bydefault alert box, it is working.

Comment: no i wanted to be shown my error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `json_encode($return);` which suggests that whatever the client is (I'm guessing client side JS), it is going to try processing the response as JSON and not as an HTML document, so any HTML in the response will be treated as an error.

Instead of outputting HTML, output JSON with the error information in it.

```
{ "error": "Cant delete all widgets" }
```

Then make the client side code responsible for displaying it to the user.

Comment: Why i am getting negative voting do u know ?